# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I try to build LINE bot using node.js by utilizing line sdk to get latest information of Covid-19 statistic. Unfortunately there was an error in the async function. The error occurred when I use LINE flex message, but fine on text message.

**Error message**

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400`

**Reference**

https://github.com/PhilipPurwoko/line-bot-webhook/blob/0d12dbceab880dd7ef42876ebff3a76d24d7bf4a/handler.js#L21

This callback suppose to return value in a JSON format file then used by callback and passed to `res.json()`. I don't understand why this error occurs, even though I've made a callback here
https://github.com/PhilipPurwoko/line-bot-webhook/blob/0d12dbceab880dd7ef42876ebff3a76d24d7bf4a/controllers/webhook.js#L7

Please someone help. I have been stuck in this issue for hours. I have read many post in forum but it doesn't help. The code is to much to be added in this post. You can go to my github issue through this link https://github.com/PhilipPurwoko/line-bot-webhook/issues/1.

I really appreciate all of your responses. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that by default, Axios throws an exception if your response status is an an error ([Status starting with a 4 or 5 is considered an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status))

Since the URL you're fetching does not seem to exist, the distant API throws responds with a 404 error and axios considers it and error.

Therefore, the code executed is within the `catch()` at line 36 instead of the code within the `then()` at line 22 in `handler.js`
Since the exeption is caught, your error handler is never triggered.

[Axios has an optional parameter to consider some status number as a valid option](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

In your axios handler, add the parameter

```
{ 
validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status < 500; // Resolve only if the status code is less than 500
  }
}
```

to the `axios.get` after the url and you should be good to go.

That or expand the error handling to display the response information.

Comment: I have tried this. This is not affecting anything. However I have migrated from line-sdk to bottender. Thank you for your response anyway